# Unable to reshape numpy row matrix into column matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

This is a very simple exercise where I need to change my row into column, but seems like it's not that simple in python

```
import numpy as np

rd = np.zeros(3)
normal = 0
for i in range(len(rd)):
    rd[i]= randrange(0,10)
    normal += rd[i]

for i in range(len(rd)):
    rd[i] = round(rd[i]/normal,3)
print(rd.shape)
x = rd.reshape((0,3))
print(x.shape)
```

Getting the error
`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3 into shape (0,3)`

Comment: `0*3=0`.  Reshape can't change the total number of elements.  (3,1) shape prints as a column

Answer (score 1):

Use `x = rd.reshape((-1,3))`.  The -1 says "make this whatever is leftover after the other axes are satisfied".

Comment: `a.reshape((-1,3))` ⇒ `array([[0, 1, 2]])` — not a column matrix

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR `column = row[:, None]`

---

The fundamental flaw in your understanding is naming a Numpy *array* a *row matrix*.  Matrices are a well defined concept and are 2D in their nature, Numpy arrays can have as many dimension as needed, and this means also a single dimension, so what you call a row matrix is just a sequence of numbers of assigned length, not a 2D data structure.

```
In [57]: a = np.arange(3)
    ...: print(a.shape, a)
(3,) [0 1 2]
```

Note that after the comma there is *nothing*, in Python `(3,)` is a *tuple* containing a single element.

To have a column matrix you have to change the number of dimensions to two, and this can be done using the `.reshape()` method of arrays — you want 3 rows and 1 column, so the target shape must be this tuple: `(3, 1)`

```
In [58]: print(a.reshape((3,1)))
[[0]
 [1]
 [2]]

In [59]: b = a.reshape((3,1)) ; print(b)
[[0]
 [1]
 [2]]
```

So far, so good BUT sometimes you don't want to use explicitly the number of rows, so you may think, I'll use the colon notation

```
In [60]: a.reshape((:,1))
  File "<ipython-input-60-e69626de0272>", line 1
    a.reshape((:,1))
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but alas, it doesn't work.

Comes to rescue Numpy's extended indexing, using it we can introduce additional dummy indexes with length equal to 1, the syntax is to use either `None` or `numpy.newaxis` in addition to other indices. An example is now overdue

```
In [61]: a[:,None]
Out[61]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])

In [62]: b = a[:,None] ; print(b)
[[0]
 [1]
 [2]]
```